# iFrame & Div ID not working as expected for iOS iFrame fix

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

iOS automatically resizes scrollable iFrames to the full height of the iFrame's content.

I've fixed it using a mixture of in-line styling & style in the head applied to a div and the iFrame, however when trying to move the styling, all to the head and assigning ID's to the Div & iFrame, the fix doesn't work.

This works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe {
                height: 600px !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><iframe src="//www.google.com/" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #iOSiFrameFix {
                height: 600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            #iOSDivFix {
                overflow: auto !important;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="iOSDivFix"><iframe id="iOSiFrameFix" src="//www.google.com/"></iframe></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. For some reason the second set of code doesn't apply the fix.

Comment: It wasn't when i made that comment. Only discernible difference is the 'width 100%'. I'd bet another style is being applied from another file or selector.

Answer (score 0):

Both sets of code work and the failure was due to misconfigured publishing settings in our CMS.